# React websocket message coming before response

Tags: reactjs, websocket

I am having a case now with websockets.
I am using Promise to read response and message from socket. Afterwards I compare them and if they have the same id, it goes through.
However, most of the time socket message is arriving (fast) before response and as a result I cannot compare socket message with response id.

```
const init = {
  get(...args) {
    return request.get(...args);
  },
  post(...args) {
    // return request.post(...args)
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let response = {};
      request
        .post(...args)
        .then((res) => {
          console.log("RESPONSE====>", res);
          response = res;
        })
        .catch((err) => reject(err));

      webSocket.onmessage = (mes) => {
        try {
          // console.log(JSON.parse(mes.data))
          let { correlation_id: socketId, status_code } = JSON.parse(mes.data);
          console.log("MESSAGE====>", socketId);
          if (socketId === response.message) {
            resolve(response);
          } else if (status_code > 300) {
            reject({ status_code });
          }
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
      };
      // resolve(response)
    });
  }


export default init;
```

Above is my code for axios requests. If you know how to resolve it, kindly help here.

Comment: can you try to send request inside onmessage callback?

Comment: It is not creating anything now

Comment: Is there a way we could use asycn/await inside it, so that socket doesn't compare ids until response is made

Comment: i don't think its achievable, server response for the request and websockets are different process, they are not tie together.

What you could try to explore, is when you arrive in your websocket callback, try to check if there is a current request ongoing, and see if you can await it before going further, but it does look tricky af. Best thing is you should try to rethink/refactor that, mostly by editing your backend payload to be able to compare in your websocket or in your response the things you need to check